# Visual Studio 2012 Keyboard Shortcuts / Keybinding Poster

Tags: visual-studio-2012, keyboard-shortcuts

In the past I have found [Visual Studio 2010 Keybinding Posters](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13189) and [Visual C# 2005 Keyboard Shortcut Reference Poster](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5008) to be very helpful.

Where are the posters for 2012?

Comment: Tell me if this is of help. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I was hoping to acquire a poster to pin up on my wall. I make annotations on the poster.

Comment: check this [link](http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2012/)

Comment: This isn't from Microsoft, but here are the default key bindings for VS 2013 if anybody's looking for it. http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2013/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [poster for Visual Studio 2017](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2017-poster/)

[image]

The poster has a "Default keyboard shortcuts" section.

2012, 2013 & 2015? No soup for you.

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to add a blank line after the line you're on. You don't have to go to the end of the line and hit the  **key**. Just leave your cursor where it is and use `Ctrl+Shift+Enter (Ctrl+Enter adds a line above)`.
- If you want to uncomment a block of commented code. You don't have to select the whole commented block. Just put your cursor somewhere in the commented block and type the uncomment chord: **Ctrl+K, U.**
- If you've got an error on line and see the little red bar that marks the **SmartTag** that provides the options for fixing the problem. You don't have to fiddle with the mouse to display the dropdown list of options. You can just type `Ctrl+. (You don't even have to move your cursor back to the line in error).`
- If you type an object name, type a period, type the first letter of the member you want and get an **IntelliSense** list with lots and lots of entries. You don't have to type the whole name of the member you want. **IntelliSense** in **Visual Studio 2010** recognizes **camel-casing**, so if you hold down the Shift key and type the capitalized letters in the member name you want, IntelliSense will give narrow the list down to that one